# AngularJS: test that an external script is effectively loaded

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, angularjs

I'm working with an external script (from http://segment.io) and I'm writting an AngularJS module to interact with it.

I am wondering how can I effectively test that their script is well loaded (except than running the real app).

Should I write an end2end test?

Thanks for your help!

```
// Service is a factory
service.load = function(apiKey) {
    // Create an async script element for analytics.js.
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = ('https:' === document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +
        'd2dq2ahtl5zl1z.cloudfront.net/analytics.js/v1/' + apiKey + '/analytics.js';

    // Find the first script element on the page and insert our script next to it.
    var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the file leaves behind a global, you can simply look for window.whatever to see if it's loaded.

one very flexible cross-browser pattern i use is what i call a sentinal. You use a wrapper function to wait for the dependencies to arrive before executing the custom code.

for example, if i was dynamically injecting jQuery into the page, and i knew it was needed for something else dynamic:

```
(function waiter(){
  if(!window.jQuery){ return setTimeout(waiter, 37); }

  $("#myDiv").fadeOut();

}())
```

this pattern works independently of any script loader or browser-specific event, and doesn't require the dependancy file to be modified, great for waiting on CDN copies of libraries.

you can easily extent the notion to await several dependencies using modern Array methods:

```
(function waiter(){
  if(![ 
       window.jQuery,            // core
       window.jQuery.fn.effect,  // jq ui
       window.jQuery.fn.whizBang // jq ui plugin

   ].every(Boolean)){ return setTimeout(waiter, 37); }

  $("#myDiv").whizBang();

}())
```

Comment: Thanks dandavis. Someone points me to an equivalent solution with Jasmine waitsFor block: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs

Answer (score 1):

Someone on the AngularJS IRC channel points me to a working solution with Jasmine waitsFor block: github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs

Below a spec following spec:

```
it('should load the API when called with api key', inject(function ($window, segmentio) {
        segmentio.load(apiKey);

        waitsFor(function() {
            return $window.analytics.initialized == true;
        }, "Segmentio never loaded", 10000);

        runs(function () {
            expect($window.analytics).toBeDefined();
            expect($window.analytics.initialized).toBeTruthy();
            // Unload
            $window.analytics = null;
        });
    }));
```